# C# Convert HEX (Korean) To Korean Letters

Tags: c#, hex

I have a Hex string that I am converting into characters. This is the function I am using.

```
    public string GetAsciiString(bool replaceNewline = true)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[data.Length + 1];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Length + 1];
        bytes[0] = opcode;
        Array.Copy(data, 0, bytes, 1, data.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte value = bytes[i];
            if ((value == '\n' || value == '\r') && !replaceNewline)
                chars[i] = (char)value;
            else if (value < 32 || value > 126)
                chars[i] = '.';
            else chars[i] = (char)value;
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

However this only displays english characters and not korean. Any idea on how I can get it to display Korean?

Edit: I see the issue was that I was converting to Ascii.

Comment: Korean characters do not exist in ASCII.

Comment: You should look into [Character Encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding). You'll need to know how the strings were encoded before being encoded into hexadecimal.

Comment: The encoding is ks_c_5601-1987

How would I get readable characters from the hex then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are multiple ways to go at this.

The operation to turn byte arrays into strings is known as *decoding*. In .NET, this is done with the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding) class. In your case, you must first find the corresponding encoding. Looking at the documentation linked above, encoding `ks_c_5601-1987` corresponds to code page `949`, so:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(949);
```

Once you have that encoding, you can use it to decode the bytes:

```
var text = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

This leaves the matter of those bytes. If you already have a byte array, you're good to go. If you have a hex string, I suggest you look into existing questions for this, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/311165/.

If your data is in a stream, I recommend you use a StreamReader for this instead:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding)) // use encoding to decode from stream
{
    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```